# CSS resizing div and images inside div on window resizing

Tags: css

I have a single div with several images next to one another. Let’s say I have 7 in a row for this example.

Now, when I resize the browser, I’d like them to stay in the same row next to each other and resize their height and width accordingly.

How would I go about this?

Current example

```
<div>
    <img src=“img1.jpg” />
    <img src=“img2.jpg” />
    <img src=“img3.jpg” />
    <img src=“img4.jpg” />
    <img src=“img5.jpg” />
    <img src=“img6.jpg” />
    <img src=“img7.jpg” />
<\div>
```

Comment: You can use CSS Flexbox. Check this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1px, 1fr)) }
  img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU5Mzk0ODk1MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjA0NDQyNA@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg" />
</div>
```

Explanation:

`display: grid` is the newest addition to the CSS layout techniques, and is the most elegant. It's [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns) in evergreen browsers, so all is good.

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1px, 1fr))` finds a way to fit within 1 fraction of the whole width (so variable with the container size, which if you place this in an empty page, will vary with screen size too) with a minimum of 1px and auto-fit to whole width, each image.

`width: 100%` is needed to make sure the image isn't skewed.

`height: auto` has the same anti-distorting function if you want to use a full IMG tag with the width and height properties (which I fully recommend due to performance issues if you aren't building an HTTP/2 compatible site) or if you edit the height accidentally using some other CSS.

By the way, **this works no matter how many images you have here**, so no need to change the fractions or the percentages every time!

One last thing: when you have lists of any sort, I'd replace the `<div>` with an `<ul>` or `<ol>` if I were you, and have `<li>`s spread like this with some more CSS magic needed but a much more semantic DOM.

Image credits: [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088247/mediaindex?ref_=tt_mv_sm).

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way is to use `calc` and `float`

```css
div img {max-width: calc(100%/7);float:left;}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600" />
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600" />
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600" />
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600" />
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600" />
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600" />
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/600" />    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Jon P below, you can use calc function of css. The other better way could be running media queries.

```
@media (min-width:1200px){
div{
   width:500px;
   }
 div > img{
         width:20%;
         height:auto;
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest way is to turn the container into a flexbox (which is also more widely supported than css-grid).

```css
  #imgs {
    display: flex;
  }
  #imgs img {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="imgs">
      <img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/angular_momentum.jpg" />
      <img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/angular_momentum.jpg" />
      <img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/angular_momentum.jpg" />
      <img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/angular_momentum.jpg" />
      <img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/angular_momentum.jpg" />
      <img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/angular_momentum.jpg" />
      <img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/angular_momentum.jpg" />    
  </div>
```

Comment: This does not resize the images to fit the available space

Comment: That's not a problem. Edited to add 100% width to the images.

Comment: The images still don't shrink to fit.

Comment: It does for me.